# A die is rolled. If a random variable X is defined as the number on the upper face, then find its probability distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A die is rolled. If a random variable X is defined as the number on the upper face, then find its probability distribution.
I don't understand what it means by "number on the upper face".

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange. A quick tour of the site (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most of your time here.

Comment: The upper face is the face you directly can see if you look down from above. If you roll a "6" you see 6 dots if you look down from above. The "number on the upper face" is what you usually count if you throw a die.

Answer (score 2):

The die on the left has $4$ as the number appearing on its upper face while the die on the right has the number $2$ appearing on its upper face.

[image]

As for the *math* problem you are being asked... you are asked to find the probability distribution for the outcome of a die when it is rolled.  To do this, figure out what values are possible, then for each value figure out the probability that it occurs.  The format your answer will be in will likely be in a table like below:

$\begin{array}{r|l}Pr(X=k)&k\\\hline Pr(X=1)&\square\\Pr(X=2)&\square\\\vdots\end{array}$

A reminder, for a probability distribution to be valid, the numbers in the right-column when writing it like this must add up to equal exactly $1$.